# jquery mobile data-rel= back troubles

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile, hyperlink

My problem is that im usign JQM and I have a back button on each site.

```
<a data-rel="back" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-icon="arrow-l" data-transition="slide" data-direction="reverse" data-iconpos="notext"></a>
```

At several pages it goes back and at other pages I can't go back with the button.
It shows me always that error in the console (it is a jquery mobile error). I'm googleing since a hour or 2 and I have only founded, that this bug was a chrome bug and it is closed.. (chromium)

**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'indexOf' of undefined**

Comment: are you using single-file or multi-files template?

Comment: @Omar I don know what you are meaning with multi-files/single/files, but when I want to show the shop, it jumps in the index to the shop id and then in javascript it shows me a other file where is the row with the datails and that is made with jquery templates

Comment: I mean you navigate between `.html` files or `#page1`, `#page2` etc...

Comment: I'm navigating with id's

Comment: Do you want a JS code to try?

Comment: sure :) everything will help's me @Omar

Comment: @Omar onclick="history.go(-1);" what do you think about that?

Comment: I would recommend `$.mobile.changePage()` do you want a demo?

Comment: **onclick** function works.. but post your method,  please @Omar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is working:

```
<a data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-icon="arrow-l" data-transition="slide" data-direction="reverse" data-iconpos="notext" onclick="history.go(-1);"></a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Or, you can use desired page id as href in a tag. (if you are navigating with page id's)

`href="#your_pageID"` will be the page id you want to go back.

```
<a href="#your_pageID" data-role="button" data-theme="b" data-icon="arrow-l" data-iconpos="notext" data-transition="slide" data-direction="reverse" data-iconshadow="false" data-inline="true">
    Back
</a>
```

Comment: @yeyene , this one really helps..... data-rel="back" gave me headache as it takes mr back to first page in mobile app. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 0):

as you said in some pages it is going back and in some pages it is showing errors.
It may be because, the pages which it is redirecting properly may not have any jquery code.
And the others which you have errors may have jquery code, and before redirecting it is calling the function.

Try This:

The pages which has errors, may have dependence on external .js files, related to it. So copy the set of files, which you may have pasted in the main layout file. and try.

Comment: I dont understand that answer but I can show you some code snippets..

http://jsfiddle.net/k68Zp/395/

in the html file there are all links to my other files